# Probability based randomzation of 2d Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, probability

How would I create a random 2D numpy matrix such that values closer to zero are given high probability?

Comment: How do you want the probability to change when closer to zero? There are many different probability functions possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gausssian distribution is highest around 0:

```
print numpy.random.randn(3,4)
```

Out:

```
[[-0.06694895 -0.4634386  -1.5856743  -0.3946314 ]
 [-1.43080135  0.24923625  0.74692133 -1.73131258]
 [ 0.48610534  0.66854414  1.19446753 -0.4729655 ]]
```